# How to parse "the wind sets tolerable fair"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> “There will be a packet to Calais, to-morrow, drawer?”
> “Yes, sir, if the weather holds and the wind sets tolerable fair. The tide will serve pretty nicely at about two in the afternoon, sir. Bed, sir?”

The preceding passage is from Dicken's *A Tale of Two Cities* Chapter 4. I wonder how to parse tolerable. I think it is used as an adverb rather than an adjective. Tolerable should be tolerably. There is no adverbial form of tolerable as "tolerable". It should have been tolerably". Again the use of "fair" in the above sentence is also adverbial. If tolerable is to qualify fair, then it should have been an adverb. Please explain.

Comment: The character is speaking the local dialect rather than standard English. You are right. In standard English he should have said tolerably, but Dickens is putting it how he thinks a Kentish boatman would say it.

Comment: I'm not sure that *the use of "fair" in the above sentence is also adverbial*. Consider: "I woke up grumpy." "I went to sleep exhausted." "The wind sets fair." In each case, the last word functions as a predicate adjective. (I'm only speculating; I'm not a sailor and don't even know exactly what "sets" means here.)

Comment: Please fix the author's name: Dickens, with an s. Dickens' A Tale of Two Cities.

Comment: [set fair](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_fair): “To develop weather that is clear and pleasant.” (Aside: The *OED* notes: “***set fair*** is usually marked on English barometers at the point indicating that the height of the mercury is 30½ inches.” [Here’s a picture.](https://www.invaluable.com/auction-lot/a-french-nickel-cased-pocket-aneroid-barometer-ci-478-c-7bc4043861)

Answer (score 11):

The word **tolerable** here is used as an adverb (i.e. it means "tolerably").

Or *reasonably*, if you will: " ... and the wind sets reasonably fair."

This was a common practice in literary English up until fairly recently - by historical standards, anyway.

You'll find a ton of adverbs pretending to be adjectives in William Shakespeare's plays (to pick a name at random ... "indifferent honest," etc.)

Comment: "I'm good" vs. "I'm well". It's not just ancient history.

Comment: @fectin: True. But - did you expect me to write an entire essay on the subject? I was tempted to, I admit, but some things are better left unsaid.

Comment: it's a great answer! My quibble was only about whether this is strictly archaic, which might, possibly, cause some other minor trip-up.

Answer (score 7):

This phrase

> the wind is fair

means that the wind is favourable. Saying

> the wind is **set** fair

means that it is reliably so. It would be tricky to get a sailing ship out of harbour if the wind is backing, veering, or gusty. It has nothing to do with how pleasant the weather might be – it is a matter of practicality.

In the posted sentence

> the wind sets tolerable fair

the verb is intransitive, and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set) gives these examples

> When a broken bone sets, it heals in a particular position.
> If a liquid or soft material sets, it becomes firm or hard.

As mentioned elsewhere with **tolerable** Dickens has the character speaking in the vernacular.

Answer (score 3):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set)
> *set* verb (cause a condition)
> to cause someone or something to be in a particular condition, or to begin doing something

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fair)
> *fair* adjective
> (of weather) pleasant and dry:
> *Fair weather was forecast for the following day.*

When the weather sets fair, it sets (itself) in a pleasant condition for the following period. More specifically, a fair wind is a favourable wind for sailing. Here is M-W:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair#:%7E:text=fair%2C%20just%2C%20equitable%2C%20impartial,what%20is%20right%20and%20proper.)
> *fair*
> favorable to a ship's course

The character is speaking of *fair weather* or, in this case, of *tolerable fair weather*.

Hence, in the same way that the weather sets (itself) *fair*, he says it sets (itself) *tolerable fair*.

From this perspective, *tolerable fair* is an adjectival phrase. The character might perhaps have said *tolerable and fair* but is not guilty of misrepresenting an adverb.

Comment: The only intransitive entry in that definition of "set" seems to require a to-infinitive. (It gives the example "I set to work right away.") This sentence apparently uses "set" intransitively but without a to-infinitive.

Comment: A fair wind is one blowing in the right direction for the intended voyage. In the era of sailing ships, the possibility of putting to sea at all might depend on this.

Comment: @Agreed. A fair wind may be favourable as well as pleasant in some more general sense. I have edited.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Google ngram brings up many instances of "weather set fair"; with *set* used intransitively; too many to quote.

Comment: @Anton it has nothing to do with pleasant weather (it might even be raining) and everything to do with the safe and predictable handling of the ship. As with sailing on the tide at 2 pm, it might be more pleasant to sail at 10 am and arrive in time for supper, but these constraints are necessities.

Comment: @WeatherVane “nothing to do with” is too strong. As an oceanographer I indeed edited to include “favourable” rather than the dictionary “pleasant”. But as an oceanographer I assure you that the pleasantness (however defined) of the weather has a deal to do with the prospects of sailing, and would probably have done so to a greater extent in the days of Dickens when travel conditions were more exposed to the weather than now.

Comment: @Anton true a ship cannot set sail in bad weather, but it is still not a matter of pleasantness, or the comfort of the passengers. Those packets were not pleasure craft but working vessels with a job to do.

Comment: @Anton My point is that the definition that you found seems not to include such meanings. Perhaps there is another definition that would fit better?

Comment: 'Pleasantness' also depends where you are.  Days filled with sunshine and no rain might be pleasing in the north, but in the tropics that could easily get unbearable, intolerable even.  Won't stop ships sailing with all those highly profitable spices, but.

Answer (score 3):

The OED has *tolerable* used as an adverb both attributively and predicatively. Attributively it means the same thing as *tolerably*, while predicatively it means *tolerably well* referring to being of tolerable health.

They include this note, with the italics in the original:

> After 1750 chiefly in inferior writers and *dialect*.

They also provide such citations as:

- 1673   *Remarques on Humours of Town* 40   
  If you can but discourse tollerable of good Wine.
- 1711   R. Steele *Spectator* No. 114. ⁋1   
  I observed a Person of a tolerable good Aspect.
- 1796   E. Parsons *Myst. Warning* III. 142   
  They halted at a tolerable large hamlet.
- 1850   H. C. Watson *Camp-fires Revol.* 63   
  We had got along thus far tolerable well.
- 1873   J. H. Beadle *Undevel. West* x. 178   
  If the ‘later rain’ has not put in an appearance, they are, in local phrase, ‘tolerable dry’.
- 1884   ‘M. Twain’ *Adventures Huckleberry Finn* i. 19   
  Her sister, Miss Watson, a tolerable slim old maid, with goggles on.

As neither Dickens nor Twain was an inferior writer, these uses therefore represent ‘rustic’ or ‘dialect’ speech.